# Getting and passing structs by value in Clojure with JNA

Tags: java, struct, clojure, jna, pass-by-value

I have a C API that I'm trying to use within Clojure, through the JNA API. My issue can best be demonstrated with the following example. Say I have this C code in a library:

```
typedef struct {
    int foo;
    int bar;
    double baz;
} MyStruct;

MyStruct createStruct() {
    MyStruct myStruct;
    myStruct.foo = 3;
    myStruct.bar = 4;
    myStruct.baz = 3.14;

    return myStruct;
}

double addStruct(MyStruct myStruct) {
    return myStruct.foo + myStruct.bar + myStruct.baz;
}
```

In this example, I'd like to call `createStruct`, and then pass that result to `addStruct`. The important point here is that `MyStruct` is **passed by value** as both a return type and an argument. At no point do I need to actually read the values of the fields in `MyStruct`.

Additionally, in my system, native functions are wrapped like this:

```
; `quux` is defined in `some-lib` and returns an `int`
(let [fn- (com.sun.jna.Function/getFunction "some-lib" "quux")]
  (fn [& args]
    (.invoke fn- Integer (to-array args))))
```

**The goal is to get a type to substitute for `Integer` above that will wrap `MyStruct` as a value.**

The only resource that I've found covering this subject is [this article](http://nakkaya.com/2009/11/16/java-native-access-from-clojure/), but it only discusses how to pass structs by reference.

**Given that, here are the different approaches I've tried to take to solve this problem**:

1. **Create a class that inherits from `Structure`**, which is JNA's [built-in mechanism for creating and using structs](https://jna.java.net/nonav/javadoc/overview-summary.html#structures). Given the information on that page, I tried to create the following class using only Clojure:

   ```
   class MyStruct extends Structure implements Structure.ByValue {
       int foo;
       int bar;
       double baz;
   }
   ```

   `deftype` doesn't work for this scenario, since the class needs to inherit from the abstract class `Structure`, and `gen-class` doesn't work because the class needs to have the public non-static fields `foo`, `bar` and `baz`.

   From what I can tell, none of the standard Clojure Java interop facilities can create the above class.
2. **Create a class that inherits from `Structure` and override the struct field getter/setter methods**. Since `gen-class` is (I believe) the only Clojure construct that allows for direct inheritance, and it doesn't support multiple public non-static fields, the next alternative is to simply not use fields at all. [Looking at the `Structure` abstract class documentation](https://jna.java.net/nonav/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Structure.html), it seems like there's a concoction of overrides possible to use 'virtual' struct fields, such that it really gets and sets data from a different source ([such as the `state` field from `gen-class`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/gen-class)). Looking through the documentation, it seems like overriding `readField`, `writeField`, and some other methods *may* have the intended effect, but the I was unclear how to do this from reading the documentation, and I couldn't find any similar examples online.
3. **Use a different storage class**. JNA has a myriad of classes for wrapping native types. I'm wondering if, rather than defining and using a `Structure`  class, I could use another generic class that can take an arbitrary number of bits (like how `Integer` can hold anything that's 4 bits wide, regardless of what type the source 'actually' is). Is it possible to, for example, say that a function returns an array of bytes of length 16 (since `sizeof(MyStruct)` is 16)? What about wrapping a fixed-size array in a container class that implements [`NativeMapped`](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/NativeMapped.html)? I couldn't find examples of how to do either.

Comment: JNA provides block memory allocation in the form of `com.sun.jna.Memory`.  From there, you can extract arbitrary types from arbitrary offsets in memory using `Pointer.getXXX()` methods.

Comment: @technomage Using `Memory` as a return type for `createStruct` returns a `Pointer`, whose address is `0x0000000400000003`. In other words, it treats the raw memory value of the struct as a pointer. When dereferencing (through any of the `read` or `getXXX` methods), it crashes the VM.

Comment: The problem is that `struct` parameter and return value semantics vary by compiler and the `Structure` layout is actually used by the native code to determine how to set up the stack properly.  I was suggesting you might be able to use `Memory` to assign an arbitrary block of memory to an existing `Structure.ByValue` instance.

Comment: You might be better off asking the clojure folks.  JNA requires the `Structure.ByValue` tag on both the actual argument and the library function mapping signature in order to pass a structure by value on to the native code.

Comment: If you *do* somehow get around defining public fields, you'd need to override the (package-protected) `getTypeInfo()` for your structure, which returns FFI type information for your structure (which is itself a structure).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clojure actually embeds a forked version of [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org), which is used for generating and loading JVM bytecode.

On top of this library, I built small DSL (that's incomplete and probably broken) that allows for creating arbitrary Java classes, with a Java-like syntax. Currently, it's just a [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/kylewlacy/536ed63e36ad10aa6e1c), and only supports extending classes, implementing interfaces, adding constructors that call superclass constructors, and fields.

Here's the solution to the above question, using this DSL:

```
(def-class MyStruct :extends    com.sun.jna.Structure
                    :implements [com.sun.jna.Structure$ByValue]
  ; Declare all the constructors, which just forward their
  ; arguments to the constructors of com.sun.jna.Structure
  (com.sun.jna.Structure [])
  (com.sun.jna.Structure [com.sun.jna.TypeMapper])
  (com.sun.jna.Structure [Integer])
  (com.sun.jna.Structure [Integer com.sun.jna.TypeMapper])
  (com.sun.jna.Structure [com.sun.jna.Pointer])
  (com.sun.jna.Structure [com.sun.jna.Pointer Integer])
  (com.sun.jna.Structure [com.sun.jna.Pointer Integer com.sun.jna.TypeMapper])

  ; Declare the fields of the struct
  ^Integer foo
  ^Integer bar
  ^Double  baz)
```

Now, I can do the following:

```
(defn createStruct [& args]
  (let [fn- (com.sun.jna.Function/getFunction "some-lib" "createStruct")]
    (.invoke fn- MyStruct (to-array args))))

(defn addStruct [& args]
  (let [fn- (com.sun.jna.Function/getFunction "some-lib" "addStruct")]
    (.invoke fn- Double (to-array args))))

(addStruct (createStruct))
; => 10.14
```